# Add columns to an SQLite table in a Python loop

Tags: python, sqlite

I make a database (using sqlite3) for a scientific program (Python). 
This program build makes loops which gradually build the database.
So the problem is to add column with a loop. I made an example. It shows that the problem is the variable which defines the new column name (`Name1`).

```
import sqlite3
import os

conn=sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c=conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE TableName (Var1 REAL, Var2 REAL)''')

Name1='Test1'
c.execute('''ALTER TABLE TableName ADD COLUMN "+Name1+" INTEGER''')
Name1='Test2'
c.execute('''ALTER TABLE TableName ADD COLUMN "+Name1+" INTEGER''')
```

Does anyone have an advice to solve this problem please ?
Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: So what about this isn't working?  If there is a traceback or any other error message, can you please edit your question to include it?

Answer (score 7):

String literals must be terminated by the same sort of quoting that started them. Thus the `"+Name1+"` is interpreted as a literal part of your strings and passed on to `c.execute(...)` without the variable `Name1` being inserted.

Thus both new columns would have the literal name `+Name1+`, which leads to the error message

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: duplicate column name: +Name1+
```

You probably wanted something like:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE TableName (Var1 REAL, Var2 REAL)''')

name1 = 'Test1'
c.execute('''ALTER TABLE TableName ADD COLUMN ''' + name1 + ''' INTEGER''')
name1 = 'Test2'
c.execute('''ALTER TABLE TableName ADD COLUMN ''' + name1 + ''' INTEGER''')
```

Rewritten with a loop, that'd be

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE TableName (Var1 REAL, Var2 REAL)''')

for column_name in ['Test1', 'Test2']:
    c.execute('''ALTER TABLE TableName ADD COLUMN ''' + column_name + ''' INTEGER''')
```

To avoid the risk of SQL injections, [you shouldn't do string concatenation or manipulation on the SQL query or command](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sqlite3.html), though. Instead use the parameter substitution Python's database API already offers:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE TableName (Var1 REAL, Var2 REAL)''')

for column_name in ['Test1', 'Test2']:
    c.execute('''ALTER TABLE TableName ADD COLUMN ? INTEGER''', (column_name,))
```

In fact, the API will make an [explicit loop unnecessary](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id18):

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE TableName (Var1 REAL, Var2 REAL)''')

column_names = [('Test1',), ('Test2',)]
c.executemany('''ALTER TABLE TableName ADD COLUMN ? INTEGER''', column_names)
```

Comment: Using parameter substitution gives me an operational error.  Also parameter substitution is designed for _values_, not _identifiers_ like column names.  In most RDBMS identifiers and values will have different quoting rules, so parameter substitution for identifiers won't work.

Comment: Hmm… I'm pretty sure it worked back when I posted this answer. Maybe sqlite got stricter in what can be a substitutable parameter? (And it probably makes sense to restrict that to actual values, even though for the usecase at hand, identifiers would be quite useful.)